# How to use Pagination filter in getOrders call (eBay Trading API)?

Tags: c#, pagination, ebay-api

I write C# application, which gets orders from Ebay.

The problem is I can get only 100 orders from getOrders.ApiResponse.OrderArray.

I have about 1000 orders. How to get other 900? In another words, how to iterate through ebay orders by using HasMoreOrders call and Pagination.PageNumber?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider reading this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before asking a question. Consider providing working code, provided input, expected output and errors if any and we will be glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

In the first GetOrders call itself you can find the total no of items and Pages in the result

You should loop through each page & call GetOrders API call with different page number

```
For(int index=0; index<Orders.Pages; index++)
{
// Build GetOrders Request with PageNumber - index

// Call GetOrders API with page number 

// Manipulate result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response itself contains the current page number and total number of pages. You will need to do a new request per page.

Take a look at the following code I wrote to get all results from each page (this is with the Finding API, but works the same for all other eBay APIs):

```
var response = GetResults(findingService, request, currentPageNumber);
if (response.ack == AckValue.Success)
{
    var result = response.searchResult;
    if (result != null && result.count > 0)
    {
        // TODO process result

        for (var i = response.paginationOutput.pageNumber; i < response.paginationOutput.totalPages; i++)
        {
            currentPageNumber += 1;

            response = GetResults(findingService, request, currentPageNumber);
            result = response.searchResult;

            // TODO process result
        }
    }
}

private FindCompletedItemsResponse GetResults(CustomFindingService service, FindCompletedItemsRequest request, int currentPageNumber)
{
    request.paginationInput = GetNextPage(currentPageNumber);
    return service.findCompletedItems(request);
}

private PageinationInput GetNextPage(int pageNumber)
{
    return new PaginationInput
    {
        entriesPerPageSpecified = true,
        entriesPerPage = 100,
        pageNumberSpecified = true,
        pageNumber = pageNumber  
    };
}
```